# Which ROS2 version for RPI4?

Tags: slam

I wasted like 2 weeks with Humble before realizing Gazebo packages were not available for ARM64/rpi4 platforms

I dont feel like trying them all, so can someone point me to a ROS2 version that is sure to be complete for RPI4 ?

thanks for your inputs

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) it is fairly straightforward to compile the ros_gazebo_bridge from source, for ROS - Gazebo combinations that are not officially supported, 2) maybe obvious, but did you consider running your ROS application on the RPI and gazebo on another system?

Comment: for some reason gazebo cannot be compiled for humble (makes no sense to me but it is a known issue) I installed foxy on a ubuntu 20.04 VM

Comment: You cannot 'compile gazebo _for_ humble'. That sentence does not make sense. You can compile Humble. You can compile a 'specific version of Gazebo', e.g. 'Garden' or 'Fortress'. If there are packages available, you do not need to compile any of these at all! However, if you want ROS and Gazebo to communicate, you also need the `ros_gz_bridge`. This is not available as a package for all ros - gazebo version combinations. So depending on your choice, this might need to be compiled from source.

Comment: Here is the `ros_gz_bridge`: https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz

Comment: thanks man ! so far I installed foxy, everything seems to work

Answer (score 0):

As for me the easiest way for a beginner is to use foxy on Ubuntu 20.04

and install these

```
ros-foxy-desktop python3-argcomplete ros-foxy-ros-base ros-dev-tools ros-foxy-diagnostic-updater ros-foxy-control-msgs ros-foxy-xacro ros-foxy-behaviortree-cpp-v3 ros-foxy-nav2-msgs ros-foxy-vision-msgs ros-foxy-realtime-tools ros-foxy-gazebo-msgs ros-foxy-gazebo-dev ros-foxy-gazebo-ros ros-foxy-control-toolbox ros-foxy-joy-teleop
```